# Information about the complexity of recursive algorithms

Tags: algorithm, recursion, equation

does anyone know about some good sources about counting complexity of recursive algorithms?
somehow recurrent equation isn't really popular title for web page or what, I just couldn't google out anything reasonable...

Comment: why so many downvotes? Just because people don't know what he's talking about? People should try to argument downvotes.

Comment: @Jack: he got downvotes because the first revision of the question had an arguably-offensive title.  I reworded the title, and the vote count has gone up significantly since.

Comment: c'mon.. i just called myslef retard, that's offensive against me only

Comment: Noticed now, that makes more sense. Finding -5 without any single comment seems just trolling.. that's why I complained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a complex topic that is not so well-documented on free licterature on internet.

I just did a similar exam and I can point you to the handbook written by my teacher: [PDF Handbook](http://rapidshare.com/files/314384085/Handbook.pdf.html)

This handbook covers mostly another tool called *generating functions* that are useful to solve any kind of recurrence without bothering too much on the kind of recurrence.

There is a good book about **Analysis of Algorithms** that is *An introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms* ([amazon link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Analysis-Algorithms-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/020140009X)) by Sedgewick and Philippe Flajolet but you won't find it online (I had to scan parts of it).

By the way I've searched over internet a lot but I haven't found any complete reference with examples useful to learn the techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have had more luck with [recurrence equation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22recurrence+equation%22+recursion+complexity).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

> In the analysis of algorithms, the
>   master theorem, which is a specific
>   case of the Akra-Bazzi theorem,
>   provides a cookbook solution in
>   asymptotic terms for recurrence
>   relations of types that occur in
>   practice. It was popularized by the
>   canonical algorithms textbook
>   Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen,
>   Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein, which
>   introduces and proves it in sections
>   4.3 and 4.4, respectively. Nevertheless, not all recurrence
>   relations can be solved with the use
>   of the master theorem.